# Is there a way I can protect certain tag Keys from deletion in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

So Lets say I have an EC2 instance which has the below tags

```
Name: "Test"
Purpose: "Business"
```

How can I write a policy which would deny users from deleting the tag with key "Name" and "Purpose" ?

I have tried with the `aws:DeleteTag`  action with `RequestTag` conditions, but they dont seem to work as expected.

I also assume that this use-case does not have anything to do with `aws:DeleteTags` not supporting `Resource level permissions`

Answer (score 1):

I see this is a bit old question. However, just leaving this to help if anyone jump here for the same. You may use something like below.

```html
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyRemoveMandatoryTags",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:DeleteTags"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
          "aws:TagKeys": [
            "Name",
            "Purpose"

          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is only for EC2 instances, you may add any additional resource actions if they supports by AWS resource actions and this conditions. Refer below link for more information.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/reference_policies_actions-resources-contextkeys.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not an immediate solution, as it doesn’t prevent the actual deletion, but AWS Config has a predefined “required-tags” rule that you can use to either raise an alarm or automatically remediate when a required Tag has not been set or removed.
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/required-tags.html

Comment: Thanks for your response.
so this would need me to act after someone deletes a tag, I will still wait for a way where i can define a policy which would verify and block when the deletetag API is called with certain tags